# Drop height vs Bounce efficiency

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, experimental-physics

[image][image]

[image]

Hi i am analysing the graph between the Bounce efficiency vs Drop height. When i calculate the uncertainty in the gradient it comes out to be a very large number. This could be due to the small change in the bounce efficiency. Could you elaborate on this.

Something in these lines:
Slope is close to 0 that is why there any percentage uncertainty even the slightest change in (bars) would have a large impact on the percentage uncertainty. If the data spared was large enough then there would a small uncertainty in the gradient.
The positive gradient of the minimum trend line suggests that there is a possibility that the overall slope is 0.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you reduce the size of your vertical error bars at $0.35$ m and $0.65$ m by making multiple drops (say ten, for example) at each height and averaging the bounce efficiency. As long as there are no significant systematic errors, this will give you a more accurate estimate of bounce efficiency at each height than a single drop will.

Then find the line of best fit through your average data points at each drop height. Comparing the lines through your extreme high and low estimates tells you very little.